# multithreaded mutisocket program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I want to made a Server Which makes a client and start conversation with him but IOException is occur in Handler's code I couldn't underStand why Br.readLine method throws Exception
Here is code of mine Server project's package's classess and two clients abc, def classes are also

This is code of Server projects classeess...............

```
        package server;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.net.ServerSocket;
        public class Server {
            private void operate() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2222);
                    while(true) new Thread(new Handler(serverSocket.accept())).start();
                } catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("IOException in operate method of Server");
                }
            }    
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                new Server().operate();
            }
        }

package server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
public class Handler implements Runnable {
    Handler(Socket s) {
        socket = s;
        counter++;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine());                 //This throw the IOExceptionnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn...............
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in "+counter+"'s run method");
        }
    }
    private final Socket socket; 
    private static int counter =0;
}
```

Code of First Client ABC...........................

```
package abc;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
public class Abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);
            while(true) new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()).println("HI from Abc");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in main ");
        }
    }
}
```

Code of Another Client DEf.........................

```
package def;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
public class DEf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);
            while(true) new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()).println("HI from Abc");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException in main ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include also the exception (its stack trace, using e.printStackTrace())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clients request the output stream repeatedly from the socket using `socket.getOutputStream()`. Instead, you should invoke this method and create a corresponding writer only once, for example:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
while(true) {
  writer.println("HI from Abc");
  ...
}
```

Same with the Handler class - create your buffered reader once.

Comment: Thanks,,,,,,,,
and new problem is
Result in continous run of server even if client stop

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted answers on Server-Client Socket Communication. Please have a look.

- [Java Server with Multiclient communication.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287439/java-server-with-multiclient-communication?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Basic echo server, client-server relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333664/basic-echo-server-client-server-relationship/22334636#22334636)

---

Try this code. It might solve you problem.

**Handler.java:**

- **Check `BufferedReader.ready()` before `BufferedReader.readLine()`**
- Use single `BufferedReader`

  ```
  class Handler implements Runnable {
      private BufferedReader reader;

      Handler(Socket s) {
          socket = s;
          counter++;
          try {
              reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      public void run() {
          try {
              while (socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed()) {
                  if(!reader.ready()){
                      continue;
                  }
                  //System.out.println("ready");
                  System.out.println(reader.readLine()); // This throw
                                                         // the
              } // IOExceptionnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn...............
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.println("IOException in " + counter + "'s run method");
          }
      }

      private final Socket socket;
      private static int counter = 0;
  }
  ```

**Abc.java:**

- Use single `PrintWriter`

  ```
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
      while (true)
          writer.println("HI from Abc");
  ```

**DEf.java:**

- Use single `PrintWriter`

  ```
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
      while (true)
          writer.println("HI from Abc");
  ```

Comment: Please let me know, if problem is still not resolved?

Comment: Are you getting this exception `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)` when any client is disconnected from server.

Comment: Thanks,,,,,,,, and new problem is Result in continous run of server even if client stop

Comment: Just un-comment `if(!reader.ready()){
                    continue;
                }` Let me update it in code.

Comment: I have updated the code. Now try it again. `reader.ready()` will solve you problem.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one more thing `socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed()`. I have updated it also.

Comment: Let me know whether it working or not? Your next problem *Result in continous run of server even if client stop.* is solved by this.

Comment: Now not even statement is reading by 
System.out.println(reader.readLine());
Just Continue running both Client and Server.....
Without any System.out

Comment: Please check it again. Its working as expected. Whenever any client is added to server then server starts to print message in infinite loop but as soon as client is closed, server also stops to print it. It comes out of `while` loop as condition that I have mentioned in my answer returns false when client is disconnected.

Comment: But Client programme ABc, DEf are not stopped even if Server Stop

Comment: OK the problem is with stopping server. Let me check it. I have tested for Client.

Comment: You have to send some message from server to client on server stop and client will read it and come out of `while` loop and close the `socket` as well as `writer`. Is this code part of GUI application then add `addWindowListener` on `Window`.

Comment: I have already shared a code for server client chat in my other posts.

Comment: Yes I Have Reading it ...
trying to understand....
It will be Great help full because i am new to io and multithreading