# Multiple threads dont seem to be working

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 classes, a server and a client. The server uses multiple threads to accept many clients. So x clients can join the same server. However in an attempt to identify the threads from the client method, I seem to have found that its not making multiple threads as the ID are the same for all clients. The code I have is as follows:

SERVER:

```
public class Server
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    int portNumber;
    public static volatile String userInput;
    public volatile int noOfClients = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Server s = new Server();
    s.startup();
}


/**
 * Start the server on the user picked port
 */
public void startup()
{   
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a port");
        Scanner dif = new Scanner(System.in);
        portNumber = Integer.parseInt(dif.nextLine());
        dif.close();

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        newThread();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


public void newThread()
{
    Thread thread =new Thread()
    {

        public void run()
        {   
            while(true) {
                try {

                    accept();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

public void accept()
{
    try
    {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        new Thread(new ClientSocket(clientSocket)).start();
        System.out.println("A new client has just connected.");
        noOfClients++;

    } catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


class ClientSocket implements Runnable {
    Socket clientSocket;

    public ClientSocket(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        {
            try
            {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                while (true)
                {
                    userInput = in.readLine();
                }

            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

CLIENT:

```
public class Client
{
    Socket clientSocket;
    public static int threadName;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String hostName = args[0];
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);


    try {
        Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println("RunnableJob is being run by " + thread.getName() + " (" + thread.getId() + ")");
        String userInput;

        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null)
        {

            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("Server: " + userInput);
        }

    } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("error in host");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error in IO");
    }


}
}
```

When running two separate clients, the

```
System.out.println("RunnableJob is being run by " + thread.getName() + " (" + thread.getId() + ")");
```

line of code prints out the same. How can i fix it so that each new client connection is started within is own UNIQUE thread. so 2 clients will have 2 threads in total? Thanks :)

Comment: You're printing the thread names on the client. Don't you want to know the thread names in your server program?

Comment: I think you meant to check the threads within the server, not the client.

Comment: @spinlok What Im wanting to do is if the thread is ID=1 do this... else do nothing, then increments to if ID=1 do this... and so on. So basically I am wanting to uniquely identify the threads and only do something with one at a time, then do the same to the next and so on. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @KyleSpence just moved that line into the server and it is giving seperate ID's. i have thought of a way I can do what I was wanting from the server class not the client, thanks for the help!

Comment: So you want to uniquely identify clients based off of their thread id?  Since they are in different runtimes, they are separate from each other.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are checking the thread ids for the clients, which are separate from each other, so that won't work.

However using a thread id is not a very good way to identify clients. Instead why don'y you keep a count of the number of clients, then when a new one joins, increment the number and give the client object that number as an id.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple clients will connect at different port no with server. You can use that port no to distinguish between clients.

You can store `ClientSocket` some where to retrieve other information of each client in future if needed as shown in below code.

Here is the code:

```
private static HashMap<Integer, ClientSocket> clientInfo = new HashMap<Integer, ClientSocket>();
class ClientSocket implements Runnable {
    Socket clientSocket;

    public ClientSocket(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        System.out.println(clientSocket.getPort());
        clientInfo.put(clientSocket.getPort(), this);
    }
    ...
```

Read more about [Java Server with Multiclient communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287439/java-server-with-multiclient-communication?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Multiple clients can connect to a server with different port numbers, and multiple clients can connect to a server [with the same port number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).  The server can be set up to work either way.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Now it depends where you want to implement the logic.