# I am doing a multiclient chat sever program in java. But I am not able to run it. Here is my code for multi client server

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
```

/* The code is able to run single client but not multiple client. When I run this program with my client class it is able to handle only one client. While I run multiple threads it lost its communication with the first thread. I don't know why. */

```
public class MultipleChatClient extends JFrame{
    Vector<HandleAClient> clients = new Vector<HandleAClient>();
    JButton btnSend = null;
    JButton btnExit = null;
    JTextArea taMessages = null;
    JTextField tfInput = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    int clientNumber = 0;
    public MultipleChatClient(){
        this.Interface();    /* creates GUI */
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(8900);
            while(true){
                socket = server.accept();
                HandleAClient task = new HandleAClient(socket); /* add every client to vector */
                clients.add(task);
                new Thread(task).start();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public class HandleAClient implements Runnable{    /* multithreaded class to handle multiclients */
        private Socket socket;
        public HandleAClient(Socket socket){
            clientNumber++;
            this.socket = socket;
        }
        public void run(){
            try{
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                while(true){
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    taMessages.append("Client Number " + clientNumber + " said: ");
                    taMessages.append(line + "\n");
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                taMessages.append("Connection Lost");
            }
        }
        public void sendMessage() {
            pw.println(tfInput.getText());

        }
    }
    public void Interface(){    /* to build GUI */
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        taMessages = new JTextArea();
        taMessages.setRows(10);
        taMessages.setColumns(50);
        taMessages.setEditable(false);
        tfInput = new JTextField(50);
        JPanel but = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1,5,10));
        but.add(btnSend);
        but.add(btnExit);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(taMessages, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        add(sp,"Ce`enter code here`nter");
        JPanel bp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        bp.add(tfInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bp.add(but, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        btnSend.addActionListener(new buttonListner());
        //btnSend.addKeyListener(new buttonListner());
        btnExit.addActionListener(new buttonListner());
        setSize(600,600);
        setTitle("Server");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        //pack();
    }
    public class buttonListner implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == btnExit){
                System.exit(1);
            }
            else{
                taMessages.append("You Said: ");
                taMessages.append(tfInput.getText() + "\n");
                for(HandleAClient c: clients){
                    c.sendMessage();
                }
                tfInput.setText(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MultipleChatClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I am not able to run it"?

Comment: Please share the server side code also to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Multi-threading`. Create a new Thread for each client connected to the server.

I have already posted some of the **samples in the same context**.

Please have a look at below posts. It might help you to understand it.

- [Java Server with Multiclient communication.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287439/java-server-with-multiclient-communication?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Multiple clients access the server concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732835/multiple-clients-access-the-server-concurrently?answertab=votes#tab-top)